# How to export yolov5.pt to TensorFlow.js model

Tags: tensorflow.js, yolov5

I am having problems converting the *yolov5.pt* model that I created into a TensorFlow.js model. Why is  the error occurring in *tensorflow_decision_forests*.

Error:

> WARNING:root:Failure to load the inference.so custom c++ tensorflow ops.
> This error is likely caused the version of TensorFlow and TensorFlow Decision Forests are not compatible.
> Full error:D:\Magang\yolo_v5\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_decision_forests\tensorflow\ops\inference\inference.so not found.
> TensorFlow.js: export failure  0.2s: D:\Magang\yolo_v5\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_decision_forests\tensorflow\ops\inference\inference.so not found

How do I solve this?